# how to know if element disappear and then appear in seleniuum python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i wanna know if element appear then disappear i want to apply it in this code
i know that internet is back by a text appear when internet is gone or its back

```html
except:
    time.sleep(3)
    if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq").size['width'] != 0 :
        print ('internet lost')
        while True:
             time.sleep(5)
             if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq").size['width'] == 0 :
                print("internet back")
             else:
               continue    
    else:
      print("nothing happen")
```

This is working fine:

if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq").size['width'] != 0
and it print 'internet lost' when the the element appear

But this is not working:

if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq").size['width'] == 0
i just want it to print " internet back " if the element is no longer present

Answer (score 0):

If the element appears or disappears you could write

```
if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq"):
```

It will return True if the element exists and False if it doesn't

Comment: i have problem with this code if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KhLQZTRq").size['width'] == 0   i want it to print "internet back if the element is no longer present